# Does object creation in the render method break 'React.PureComponent' and render checking in 'shouldComponentUpdate'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tl;dr: when you create objects / components in the render method to be passed as props / children to the rendered components, does it fail the checking of React.PureComponent and prop checks in shouldComponentUpdate?

I'm seeing patterns similar to this a lot:

```
  render() {
    const commentTrigger = <Button>Comment</Button>;
    const deleteTrigger = <Button>Delete Thread</Button>;
    const someComponentProps = { 
      prop1: this.getProp1()
      prop2: this.props.prop2
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <SomeModal trigger={commentTrigger} />
        <SomeOtherModal trigger={deleteTrigger} />
        <SomeComponent {...someComponentProps}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

would this fail the .PureComponent check or shouldComponentUpdate check in SomeComponent, since someComponentProps is a different object every time, and in particular (assuming this.getProp1() is a newly created object) would prop1 alone cause these tests to fail and end up re-rendering the component? How about if this.getProp1() is just a number?

Otherwise, is there any good reason to not write React components in this way? 
Thanks for your help in advance. Let me know if I should rephrase the question or clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PureComponent will do a shallow comparison of its props, basically using the [Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) comparison. In the case of objects, that means it will only pass if it's the same object, not if it's a different object with all the same properties.

So your first two examples (commentTrigger and deleteTrigger) are going to run into this. They're brand new objects each time you render, unrelated to the previous ones, and thus will not pass a triple equals.

In your third example (spreading someComponentProps), it makes no difference whether someComponentProps is a new object or not. By spreading it, you are passing in a sequence of individual props, starting with `prop1={someComponentProps.prop1}` and running through the rest of the properties on the object. It's a convenient syntax when you don't know how many props there are. If SomeComponent is a pure component, it will check whether prop1 changed and whether prop2 changed, with no idea that someComponentProps even existed.

Comment: thanks for the help, it makes a lot more sense. for the first two examples, would it be better to create separate functional components and insert them as props directly, so that they are always the same?

Comment: There's a few options at your disposal. I don't know what to recommend since i don't know what the prop will be used for. Yes, one option is to make SomeModal expect you to pass a component. But you may need more control than that, in which case you could look into doing a render prop https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). You'd then pass a function in to SomeModal, and you'd have that function be a method on your main component (ie, its not created in render). A third option is to write a custom shouldComponentUpdate which ignores the trigger prop so it doesn't matter if you change it.

Answer (score 1):

`PureComponent` does shallow equality check of props object. In case next `prop1` value (created with `this.getProp1()`) is `===` equal to previous value, so is `prop2`, `SomeComponent` won't be updated.

Even if props aren't `===` equal, custom checks can be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate`, e.g. deep equality check.